# Why is this method to obtain CPU utilization produces results 2 times lower than that from the Task Manager?

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-10, cpu-usage

I'm using the following method to detect CPU utilization:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

int get_CPU_Usage(void);


int main()
{
    COORD c = {0};
    HANDLE hStdOut = ::GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    for(;; ::Sleep(500))
    {
        ::SetConsoleCursorPosition(hStdOut, c);
        wprintf(L"Current CPU usage: %d%%\t\t\n", get_CPU_Usage());
    }

}




int get_CPU_Usage(void)
{
    //RETURN: = CPU Usage in percent [0 - 100], or
    //        = -1 if error
    int nRes = -1;

    //Run system function
    FILETIME ftIdle, ftKrnl, ftUsr;
    if(::GetSystemTimes(&ftIdle, &ftKrnl, &ftUsr))
    {
        //Now calculate value
        static BOOL bUsedOnce = FALSE;
        static ULONGLONG uOldIdle = 0;
        static ULONGLONG uOldKrnl = 0;
        static ULONGLONG uOldUsr = 0;

        ULONGLONG uIdle = ((ULONGLONG)ftIdle.dwHighDateTime << 32) | ftIdle.dwLowDateTime;
        ULONGLONG uKrnl = ((ULONGLONG)ftKrnl.dwHighDateTime << 32) | ftKrnl.dwLowDateTime;
        ULONGLONG uUsr = ((ULONGLONG)ftUsr.dwHighDateTime << 32) | ftUsr.dwLowDateTime;

        //Only if we have previous values
        if(bUsedOnce)
        {
            ULONGLONG uDiffIdle = uIdle - uOldIdle;
            ULONGLONG uDiffKrnl = uKrnl - uOldKrnl;
            ULONGLONG uDiffUsr = uUsr - uOldUsr;

            if(uDiffKrnl + uDiffUsr)
            {
                //Calculate percentage
                nRes = (int)((uDiffKrnl + uDiffUsr - uDiffIdle) * 100 / (uDiffKrnl + uDiffUsr));

                //Check value and correct it (Just in case)
                if(nRes < 0)
                    nRes = 0;
                else if(nRes > 100)
                    nRes = 100;
            }
        }

        //Remember data
        bUsedOnce = TRUE;
        uOldIdle = uIdle;
        uOldKrnl = uKrnl;
        uOldUsr = uUsr;
    }

    return nRes;
}
```

It used to provide comparable reading on my old computer running Windows 8.1, but now when I'm running it on this desktop with `Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-7940X CPU @ 3.10GHz` on Windows 10 Pro, the results it gives me seem to be 2 times lower than what Task Manager is showing:

[image]

*It's hard to catch it with a screenshot, but I could definitely see consistently lower numbers from my code above.*

So I'm wondering, why such disparity?

PS. The CPU I'm testing it on has 14 physical and 28 logic cores. Could that somehow influence the output of the `GetSystemTimes` function?

Comment: Try increasing your sleep to 1 second, which is how fast task manager updates its values. It works on my machines.

Comment: @aybassiouny: thanks. But it still seems to be somewhat lower than the Task Manger. Why would it matter though?

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 10 the task manager is hyper threading aware. Lets say you have 2 physical and total of 4 logical cores. Put 2 cores at full load and tasklist will show 100% while your method will show 50%, when all 4 logical cores are filled then tasklist will still show 100% and then your method will also show 100%.

Comment: Yeah, that sounds more like the truth on Win10. So how would you determine that with WinAPI?

Comment: GetLogicalProcessorInformation seems to be right API call. Now if you run on virtual server then that usually does not matter since the logical/physical core info is not exposed to the guest OS.

Comment: OK. I would really help if you could put all this theory into code. Otherwise I don't know what to think about your suggestions.